# Can you use a shield with shield spikes to make a bludgeoning attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, shield

With any regular shield, typically one makes bludgeoning damage with a shield bash. If you add shield spikes, it changes the damage die and type to piercing. Would it be possible still use the altered shield for a lower damage bludgeoning attack if so desired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### ***No***

> These spikes **turn a shield into** a martial piercing weapon... ([d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/shield-spikes/), emphasis mine.)

The shield *becomes* a martial piercing weapon *instead of* a martial bludgeoning weapon. It effectively loses its bludgeoning key-word and changes type.